# How to move a character in pygame without making more than one picture

Tags: python, pygame

I am making my first game in pygame, but when I have generated my world and try to move my character his sprite is still left in the old position. I can't blit my background every frame either as its too large and grinds pygame's performance to a halt.

I tried bliting every frame but that also slowed pygame down as well. Then I tried to make it blit around the character so it covers the old pic of my character, but I couldn't get that to work either.

```
def MakeTerrain():
    TempY = 0
    for o in range(51):
        for i in range(51):
            TempX = 16 * i
            if TempX >= 800:
                TempY = 16 * o
                TempX = 0
            rnd = random.randrange(10)
            if rnd <= 8:
                tile = Tile("Grass",[TempX,TempY])
            else:
                tile = Tile("Stone",[TempX,TempY])

            Tiles.append(tile)
            tile.BlitTile(Display)
```

Function for making my terrain [a.k.a world/background]

```
class Player():
def __init__(self,MovementSpeed=1):
    self.DirectionX = 0
    self.DirectionY = 0
    self.PlayerPos = [0,0]
    self.MovementSpeed = MovementSpeed
    self.PlayerSprite = pygame.image.load("Jeffrey.png")

def BlitPlayer(self,display):
    display.blit(self.PlayerSprite,(self.PlayerPos[0],self.PlayerPos[1]))
```

Class of my player with my blit function

```
class Tile():
    def __init__(self,sprite,Position):
        self.TilePosition = Position
        self.TileSprite = pygame.image.load(sprite+".png")

    def BlitTile(self,display):
        display.blit(self.TileSprite,(self.TilePosition[0],self.TilePosition[1]))
```

Tile class

http://prntscr.com/nrtnyx

This is what happens

Comment: I'm not exactly understanding what you want here, it looks like you just need to fill the screen at every iteration in order to prevent overlap. But, if all youre doing is blitting the background before the player, that should not overload pygames capacity. Are you sure you aren't regenerating the entire map in every iteration of the loop?

Comment: I tried to blit from the BlitTile function on every Tile object every frame but that just makes pygame fps go down too much

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. You're drawing 2500+ tiles every single frame. Blit isnt an expensive function but with that number of objects it begins to compound. Ill try to make an answer to optimize it.

Comment: I know I blit 2500 Tiles every frame but I dont know how to do it otherwise

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea of only redrawing the tiles near the player can work, but it needs to be reworked slightly.

This will require changing your position values to `pygame.math.Vector2`, so do that first, I would also recommend changing all instances of these values to `self.pos` so that the loop I will show you is easier to make.

```
self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(Position)
```

To ascess the x and y values, they are simply `self.pos.x` or `self.pos.y`

Within the drawing code, you can first change it so it iterates through every sprite:

```
for sprite in my_sprites:
    pass
```

Inside this loop, you can check the distance from the sprite to the player using these new vectors:

```
deltaVec = player.pos - sprite.pos # Find delta [difference] between player position and sprite position
len = deltaVec.length() # Find the length between those two points through the distance formula
```

Then, at the end, check to see if the new distance is under a certain threshhold:

```
if len < 100: # 100 being the distance, change if needed
    sprite.draw()
```

In the end, the new drawing code would look like this:

```
for sprite in my_sprites:
    deltaVec = player.pos - sprite.pos
    len = deltaVec.length() 

    if len < 100: # 100 being the distance, change if needed
        sprite.draw()
```

This should only redraw the tiles nearest to the player and thats it without having to deal with managing each tile.